# getPastEvents undefined(please help)

Tags: web3js, events, react

I had asked this question before. I looked carefully at the exchange section, which I advised, and I think there is no problem with the exchange section. At least in my opinion there is no problem and I hardly know the cause of the problem. And I was so frustrated that I put everything in the code. If anyone can provide us with a clue to this problem, please reply to me

[image]

interactions.js

```
import Web3 from 'web3'
import {
  web3Loaded,
  web3AccountLoaded,
  tokenLoaded,
  exchangeLoaded,
  cancelledOrdersLoaded
} from './actions'
import Token from '../abis/Token.json'
import Exchange from '../abis/Exchange.json'

export const loadWeb3 = (dispatch) => {
  const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'http://localhost:7545')
  dispatch(web3Loaded(web3))
  return web3
}

export const loadAccount = async (web3, dispatch) => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  const account = accounts[0]
  dispatch(web3AccountLoaded(account))
  return account
}

export const loadToken = async (web3, networkId, dispatch) => {
    try {
        const token = new web3.eth.Contract(Token.abi, Token.networks[networkId].address)       
        dispatch(tokenLoaded(token))
        return token
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Contract not deployed to the current network. Please select another network with Metamask.')
        return null
    }
} 

export const loadExchange = async (web3, networkId, dispatch) => {
  try {
    const exchange = new web3.eth.Contract(Exchange.abi, Exchange.networks[networkId].address)      
    dispatch(exchangeLoaded(exchange))
    return exchange
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Contract not deployed to the current network. Please select another network with Metamask.')
    return null
  }
}
export const loadAllOrders = async (exchange, dispatch) => {
  // if (exchange) { // Make sure exchange has been defined
    // const exchange = new web3.eth.Contract(Exchange.abi, Exchange.networks[networkId].address)
     const cancelStream = await exchange.getPastEvents('Cancel', { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' })
     // // await loadAllOrders(this.props.exchange, dispatch)
     console.log(cancelStream)
  }
```

Content.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { exchangeSelector } from '../store/selectors'
import { loadAllOrders } from '../store/interactions'

class Content extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadBlockchainData(this.props.dispatch)
  }

  // async loadBlockchainData(exchange, dispatch) {
  async loadBlockchainData(dispatch) {
    await loadAllOrders(this.props.exchange, dispatch)
    // this.loadBlockchainData(this.props.exchange)
      // await loadAllOrders(exchange, dispatch)
  }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    exchange: state.exchangeSelector
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Content)
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import Web3 from 'web3';   
import Content from './Content'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
// import Token from '../abis/Token.json'
import {
  loadWeb3,
  loadAccount,
  loadToken,
  loadExchange
} from '../store/interactions'
import { contractsLoadedSelector } from '../store/selectors'

class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {    
    this.loadBlockchainData(this.props.dispatch)
  }

async loadBlockchainData(dispatch) {
    const web3 = loadWeb3(dispatch)
    const network = await web3.eth.net.getNetworkType()
    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId()
    const accounts = await loadAccount(web3, dispatch)
    const token = await loadToken(web3, networkId, dispatch)
    if(!token) {
      window.alert('Token smart contract not detected on the current network. Please select another network with Metamask.')
      return
    }
    const exchange = await loadExchange(web3, networkId, dispatch)
    if(!exchange) {
      window.alert('Exchange smart contract not detected on the current network. Please select another network with Metamask.')
      return
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Navbar />
        { this.props.contractsLoaded ? <Content /> : <div className="content"></div> }
           </div>
           );
         }
       }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    contractsLoaded: contractsLoadedSelector(state)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Comment: I think those methods need WebSocket and not Http connection, but im 100% not sure.

Comment: From your error message you are trying to use `exchange` before it is assigned a value. This is related to Ethereum but how your events are being dispatched. Also you have two different `loadBlockchainData`, are you sure you are calling the right one?

Comment: Well, thank you for all the comment. I will try hard.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by:

1. Checking Ganache UI for the 'Current Block' number.
2. Pasting that number in as a replacement for 'toBlock: 'Latest'}' in the interactions.js file.